# Visual Studio did not detect Maui projects

Tags: .net, maui

In mac, I have upgraded the Visual Studio to the 17.0 Preview version. After that, I got issue like MAUI projects are not supported this version of Visual Studio. Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you followed this guide to install VS mac? https://dev.to/davidortinau/installing-net-maui-on-macos-4mmc

Comment: @FreakyAli,  Yes. I followed this guidelines to configure MAUI in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly like it says in the warning message: at this time, even in Visual Studio for Mac preview, there is no support for .NET MAUI yet.

In the [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-for-mac-preview-7/#xamarin-mobile-tooling-is-back-and-ready-for-your-feedback) that was just posted at the time of writing this about Preview 7 it says:

> Although we don’t plan to ship .NET MAUI support with 17.0 GA, we are making great progress towards the MAUI experience and will continue to provide updates as we get closer.

If you want to work with .NET MAUI on a Mac right now, you will have to use command-line tooling.

Answer (score 0):

Gerald has pointed out that .NET MAUI is not supported on VS on a Mac right now.

However (and this may be why you’ve asked the question) it has been possible to use VS for MAUI development on the Mac. I have been doing this successfully until today when I updated VS and then got the same message as you saying that it’s not supported.

I think that it is something about the latest build. I used Time Machine on my Mac to restore my previous version of VS preview but instead of replacing the new version I’ve kept both.
I now have the newly updated version (VS 17.0 build 8001) that displays the error and can’t be used for MAUI, and alongside it have the version that I was using (VS 17.0 build 7303) that doesn’t display the error and still works for MAUI.

So to answer your question: If, like me, you had a working version that stopped working after the update (which is what I thought when I read your post) and you use Time Machine you could try restoring your old VS while keeping the new one. If you haven’t got Time Machine, hopefully this might give you some clues of what to try. Good Luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for the addition here. You are totally right! The full story is that it sort of worked, but we don't want to make it appear as it's fully supported. Basically the same happened with VS2022 on Windows. .NET MAUI Projects are now actively blocked. Probably because GA for VSMac is coming closer. It will probably then be enabled again for the VSMac Previews that come after GA