# Error: .NET 6 Xamarin and MAUI projects are not supported with this version of Visual Studio. The included target frameworks are not supported: net6.0

Tags: visual-studio-mac, maui

Unable to build .Net Maui application on IOS Physical device after connecting to mac machine getting the following error.
`Error: .NET 6 Xamarin and MAUI projects are not supported with this version of Visual Studio. The included target frameworks are not supported: net6.0-android|net6.0-ios|net6.0-maccatalyst.` VS IDE used VS2022 Preview 17.0 for Mac and Mac OS version 12.3 and xCode version 13.3.
Please help on this.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5508#issuecomment-1076114641

Comment: VS Mac does not have MAUI support yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio did not detect Maui projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507287/visual-studio-did-not-detect-maui-projects)

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507287/visual-studio-did-not-detect-maui-projects

Answer (score 1):

This was a known-issue in Visual Studio for Mac 2022 Preview 7 that [has been fixed in Visual Studio for Mac 2022 Preview 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-for-mac-preview-8/?WT.mc_id=mobile-0000-bramin):

> Thanks to reports from developers like you, we’ve addressed a handful of critical issues. Here are some of the top customer-reported issues fixed in this release:
>
> - Many keyboard shortcuts don’t work
> - Fuzzy Text [on an external monitor]
> - Android Device Manager Crashes
> - Removing an Unsupported prompt for .NET MAUI Projects